# Name of a novel in two parts where protagonist dies, but his soul gets reinserted into a descendant

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation

It's involving souls from dead bodies orbiting Earth, getting destroyed by starships with electromagnetic fields for propulsion. The protagonist is male, heroic, and physically strong; and he dies halfway through the book but gets reborn somehow in his descendant's body with poor eye-sight, asthma, and generally weak — so he sets about strengthening his new body.

I've been searching for a decade for the name of this book.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there any chance you could provide us with some non-plot details about this book? Country/language? Length? Anything memorable about the cover? Even the smallest detail could help.

Answer (score 5):

Bob Shaw. Palace of Eternity. Probably.

http://sciencefictionfantasy.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/palace-of-eternity-by-bob-shaw.html

From the link:

*Mack Tavernor .... is killed ..... He regains consciousness as an egon, a self-sustaining energy pattern ..... drifting in space around the planet ..... He also discovers that humanity is unwittingly causing devastation because the egons can be destroyed – if they come within reach of the powerful electromagnetic fields of the butterfly ships ..... Tavernor ..... return[s] to the planet's surface to occupy a human body again.*